# Find the Homepage file containing the Login Button script in phpfox

Tags: php, phpfox

I am using the *Neutron* version of the *PHPFOX Pro (v4.5)*.

At the homepage where the login button and the register button are, I have a problem with the Login Button, and I want to change the `onClick` event from *ajax popup* to a different file (which is located at

> PHPBase/module/user/template/default/controller/login.html.php

Now the problem is that I can’t seem to find the file where the Login button and onClick event are. I would be grateful if somebody with a knowledge as to where that file containing the Login button is located.

**Thanks for helping**

Answer (score 1):

$('.popup').click is what you are searching. You can find it in below path:

> /PF.Base/static/jscript/thickbox/thickbox.js